# Regex for replace msgstr in PO file data using python

Tags: python, regex, po-file

I have list `content = ['x', 'y', 'z']`

**.po file content:**

```
msgid 'abc'
msgstr ''

msgid 'def'
msgstr ''

msgid 'ghi'
msgstr ''
```

I need output like below:

```
msgid 'abc'
msgstr 'x'

msgid 'def'
msgstr 'y'

msgid 'ghi'
msgstr 'z'
```

**Edit:**

```
with io.open('file.po, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as pofile:
    filedata = pofile.read()
```

So filedata has all content of PO file

Comment: Not possible through one step, you need a loop for it.

Comment: I have PO file data into var and I need to replace content in that var but
I don't know how to replace data in exact location using python re

Comment: @revo Tell me how can achieve with loop to replace or put data in PO file content?

Comment: @NeErAjKuMaR is this VAR a string?

Comment: Find the number of all matches. Implement a for loop on that to limit the number of iterations and do `re.sub` inside.

Comment: @salparadise check my edit

Comment: @revo But How can I find all matches?. I need to regex for match and replace content from list data. Put code here. This is already mentioned in question title

Comment: Is it an issue for you to find all matches too? SO has lots of it, just a matter of searching.

Comment: @NeErAjKuMaR, you already got a short working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using built-in `iter()` function and `re.sub()` function:

```
import re

content = ['x', 'y', 'z']
po_data = '''
msgid 'abc'
msgstr ''

msgid 'def'
msgstr ''

msgid 'ghi'
msgstr ''
'''

content_it = iter(content)    # constructing iterator object from iterable
result = re.sub(r'(msgstr )\'\'', lambda m: "%s'%s'" % (m.group(1), next(content_it)), po_data)

print(result)
```

The output:

```
msgid 'abc'
msgstr 'x'

msgid 'def'
msgstr 'y'

msgid 'ghi'
msgstr 'z'
```

Answer (score 0):

Might need to explain more about the relationship of your data. You want to write the entries based on order or is there some relationship between 'abc' and 'x' for example. Anyways, here is if you want ordering (not regex):

```
In [30]: cat /tmp/somefile
msgid 'abc'
msgstr ''

msgid 'def'
msgstr ''

msgid 'ghi'
msgstr ''

In [31]: content = ['x', 'y', 'z']

In [32]: with open('/tmp/somefile', 'r') as fh, open('/tmp/somenewfile', 'w') as fw:
    ...:     for line in fh:
    ...:         if 'msgstr' in line:
    ...:             line = "msgstr '{}'\n".format(content.pop(0))
    ...:         fw.write(line)
    ...:
    ...:

In [33]: cat /tmp/somenewfile
msgid 'abc'
msgstr 'x'

msgid 'def'
msgstr 'y'

msgid 'ghi'
msgstr 'z'
```

EDIT, change file inplace (make sure you save a copy of the file)

```
with open('/tmp/somefile', 'r+') as fw:
    lines = fw.readlines()
    fw.seek(0)
    fw.truncate()
    for line in lines:
        if 'msgstr' in line:
            line = "msgstr '{}'\n".format(content.pop(0))
        fw.write(line)
```

Comment: fh is iterating as a single character, not a line

Comment: and also one thing I need to override content on same, not a new file.

Comment: I have some strings in different language like: Arabic that cause error. UnicodeEncodeError.